# Is $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \log \lvert t^2 e^{2\pi i x} - t e^{2\pi i y} + e^{2\pi i z} \rvert dx\,dy\,dz$ identically zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function

The following question came up while playing around with the [Mahler measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_measure#Higher-dimensional_Mahler_measure).  Consider the function $f$ defined by the triple integral
$$f(t) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \log \lvert t^2 e^{2\pi i x} - t e^{2\pi i y} + e^{2\pi i z}\rvert dx\,dy\,dz$$
where $t$ is in the unit interval $I = [0, 1]$.  I have shown that $f(t) \ge 0$ on $I$ and I expect the inequality to be strict for $t > 0$.  Matlab suggests that $f(t)$ is strictly increasing, with a maximum of $0.323...$ at $t = 1$; however, Mathematica thinks $f(t) \equiv 0$ on $I$. What's the truth?

Comment: Mathematica gives the same answer as Matlab: Mathematica code: `G[t_] := NIntegrate[
  Log[Abs[t^2 Exp[2 Pi I x] - t Exp[2 Pi I y] + Exp[2 Pi I z]]], {x, 
   0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]; ListLinePlot[
 Table[{t, G[t] // Re}, {t, 10^-5, 1, 1/50}], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: note that if $t^2+t \le 1$ so $| t^2 e^{2\pi i x} - t e^{2\pi i y}| \le 1$ then fixing $x,y$ and integrating $dz$ we get the integral identically zero as $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |a-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=0, |a| \le 1$; (more generally $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |a-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=2\pi \log^+|a|$); so for $t^2+t>1$ the integral in $dz$ is $\log^+ | t^2 e^{2\pi i x} - t e^{2\pi i y}|$ and hence $f$ is positive and likely increasing

Comment: Thank you both!! I tried to prove $f$ is increasing by differentiating under the integral sign, but it was horribly messy. Any other ideas?

Comment: Note that $\log^+ | t^2 e^{2\pi i x} - t e^{2\pi i y}|=\log^+ | t^2 - t e^{2\pi i (y-x)}|$ and for fixed $|w|=1$ if $|t^2-tw| \ge 1$ and $1 \ge u \ge t$, then first $|u^2-uw| \ge 1$ and then $|u^2-uw| \ge |t^2-tw| $ so the domain of the remaining double integral in $x,y$ increases with $t$, while the (non negative) integrand also increases for the common part when $u \ge t$ so the integral increases, hence $f$ does